# Check if second argument exist in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, args

I'm passing two arguments to a java job and I want to print a message if either argument is empty. I tried a few things and still get an error when my second argument is empty. I can't get past having something for my first argument and nothing for my second.

```
if (args.length == 0)
if (args.length > 1)
if (args[0].equal(0) || args[1].equal(0))
```

Comment: ```if (args.length < 2 || args[1] == 0) /* fail */```? It's difficult when we don't know anything about what args expects

Comment: The arguments passed to the `main` method arrive as `String` objects. So you cannot compare to an integer number.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your arguments.

You can use something like this:

```
if (args.length < 2 || args[0].isBlank() || args[1].isBlank()) {
   // do whatever you need to do :-)
   System.out.println("invalid arguments");
   return;
}
```

Notice that isBlank() needs Java 11, you can use isEmpty if you don't have Java 11, but that does not compare white spaces. Or you can use functions from Apache Commons StringUtils, etc. to check the length (or implement it yourself).

Answer (score 1):

As [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque) has mentioned in the comment, the arguments to `main` method are `String` values i.e. if at all you need to check if the argument is `0`, you need to check it as `args[0].equals("0")` instead of `args[0].equal(0)`.

However, if I understood your question correctly, you only want to check if one or both of the arguments are missing. You can write your checks as follows:

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Arguments are missing");
    // ...
} else if (args.length == 1) {
    System.out.println("The second arguments is missing");
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Note that a bank or white space argument to `main` will automatically be discarded. Therefore, you do not need to test if any of the arguments are empty or blank.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed to the `main` method arrive as `String` objects. So you cannot compare to an integer number.

You can loop the arguments, checking to see if the string is empty or blank.

```
for( String arg : args )
{
    if( arg.isEmpty() || arg.isBlank() ) 
    {
        …
    } else 
    {
        int number = Integer.parseInt( arg ) ;  // Add try-catch for `NumberFormatException`.
        if( number == 0 ) { … }
    }
}
```